# Accidentally deleting all submodules from maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij and have a java SpringBoot project called ?University", under this project I have two submodules "Professors" and "Students". I did not know what I did but those submodules were somehow deleted from my maven dependency. In my Maven management interface, now I only have a file called "University", and it says module "Professors" not found and module "Students" not found when I clicked on it. All my files are still there, and I tried right clicking on their pom.xml file and adding them as Maven projects. Even though they are now back in my Maven management interface, "University" still cannot detect them. What should I do?

I imagine I need somehow add them back to University as submodules of it, but I searched everywhere and did not find any clues on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you parent POM should define

```
 <modules>
    <module>Professors</module>
    <module>Students</module>
</modules>
```

and Professors and Students are 2 folders (name is case-sensitive) with 2 submodules, each one with its own POM file.

Comment: I already had those set up in my POM but still did not work, Professors and Students are marked red in my POM